# Convert Dictionary<string, Task<string>> to Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, microsoft-metro

I don't want to use a `foreach` loop twice, so I tried to use LINQ, but unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
return _etags.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, async item => await item.Value);
```

Can anyone tell me what should I do to improve my code, or how can I convert `Dictionary<string, Task<string>>` to `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Here is my code:

```
private static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetETagsAsync(List<string> feedsLink)
{
    var eTags = new Dictionary<string, string>(feedsLink.Count);
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    var _eTags = new Dictionary<string, Task<string>>(feedsLink.Count);
    eTags = new Dictionary<string, string>(feedsLink.Count);
    foreach (string feedLink in feedsLink)
    {
        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(feedLink, UriKind.Absolute))
        {
            _eTags.Add(feedLink, GetETagAsync(feedLink));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FormatException();
        }
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Task<string>> eTag in _eTags)
        {
            eTags.Add(eTag.Key, await eTag.Value);
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        return eTags;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value.Result);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not want to throw an Exception in after you started some tasks, better validate first.

```
    private static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetETagsAsync(List<string> feedsLink)
    {
        ValidateFeedsLinkFormat(feedsLink);

        var _eTags = feedsLink.ToDictionary(f => f, f => GetETagAsync(f));
        await TaskEx.WhenAll(_eTags.Values);

        var eTags = _eTags.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value.Result);

        return eTags;
    }
```

This code starts all the tasks, as yours did, but with a single await for all the links.
You do not want to use an instance of Stopwatch on multiple threads : from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx): "Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."
You can use `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();` twice and compare the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, now my code looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/6Qnyn4j1

I've got one more question. As you see I use method GetETagAsync and in this method looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/p2TzC48x

I have also validated links. Shall I validate link in this previous method (GetETagsAsync)? And is GetETagAsync written correct?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to validate link in GetETagAsync because it's private and it's called only from your code. It's better to bulk validate your data if you want all or nothing, but if you want to to load what can be loaded, validate in GetETagAsync and use a try/catch block.

Comment: It's not a good practice to throw exceptions, maybe you can use a return class instead, or at least specify all the problems, not an empty Exception

Comment: Why shouldn't I throw exceptions? I use it in this way:
http://pastebin.com/0YYqQY74